# how can I snap windows to fixed position on my desktop?

Tags: windows, desktop-application, desktop

For example, I have 4 windows opened on my desktop. I want a quick way to arrange them in all four corners with same the size. Or any dimensions I choose on Windows 7.

Are the programs like that out there?

Comment: Does this answer the question: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/11073/stupid-geek-tricks-tile-or-cascade-multiple-windows-in-windows-7/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is possible without the need of any additional program. Try [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/181681/4-hidden-window-management-tricks-on-the-windows-desktop/) for some quick tips on how to arrange your windows in all forms. You might find what you are looking for there.

Comment: THanks but this article helped. Thought I share. http://www.7tutorials.com/how-snap-windows-side-side-dual-multi-monitor-setup